# Buttons dissapearing after changing State UI Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angular-ui-router

I have a question regarding changing states.

When i change states with my app my buttons in the headers dissapear.

I have made an app in this link:

http://play.ionic.io/app/2f5cc1913037

Anyone help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Ionic Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/menuToggle/):

> **Button Hidden On Child Views**
>
> By default, the menu toggle button will only appear on a root level side-menu page. Navigating in to child views will hide the menu- toggle button. They can be made visible on child pages by setting the enable-menu-with-back-views attribute of the ionSideMenus directive to true.
>
> `<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">`

[Working DEMO](http://play.ionic.io/app/817cc4d270f0)